# Moved a folder in my nextJS project, now I get moduleNotFoundError

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, modulenotfounderror

Was wondering if someone could help me on this:

I'm trying to run

> npm run build

for my NextJS project (created via create-next-app).

I'm getting this error when building:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/ProductImages' in 'C:\Users\shira\Documents\Web\Projects\amp-react-theme\pages'
```

I initally had a folder called "components" where my components were being held inside the pages folder. Realizing it shouldn't be there, I moved the folder out and put it on the project root. Now it's giving me this error.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? It looks like one/+ of your files inside of your pages directory is trying to reference the ProductImages component but it is no longer in the right place.

Comment: If you are using vscode, you can search on the searchbar for this ' ../components/ProductImages', locate the file and type the file path, vscode should auto suggest the path as you type, so you can locate the component and import it correctly

Comment: Just searched for that and I've rectified the error by updating my imports, so thanks :). Now I get another error when deploying via Vercel:

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../graphql/Queries' in '/vercel/path0/pages'

Queries was accidently placed in the pages folder in the past and was moved to the project root later.

I can build the project locally, but when deploying, it gives a modulenotfoundError.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.